# document.getElementById() returns null on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I'm working on a popup and i'm having some hard time with Internet Explorer 9. This is the piece of code that gives me trouble:

```
var popUp= document.getElementById('projectInfo');
popUp.style.left=(tempX-310)+'px';
popUp.style.top=(tempY-110)+'px';
```

In IE9 (haven't tested in prior versions), popup is null. In adition, i've tried including my .js file just before the body closing tag and wrapping my function in a "document.ready()" function but none of this worked. The same code though works perfectly in Opera, Chrome and Firefox. 
Does anyone know what's going on?

Note: The function is called in the body's onLoad atribute of my html.

Comment: Can you include the HTML?

Comment: These links seem relevant: - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/iewebdevelopment/thread/dca80bb2-20b2-4029-8600-cd363cc64ddd
- http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/issues/detail?id=616 Are you using any non-standard HTML attributes in your HTML - or possibly something like svgweb?

Comment: @Trevor That should be a `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of null` error.

Comment: Hi Ziesemer, thank you for your time. I'm not using svgweb nor non-standar HTML attributes. Just this simple div `<div id='projectInfo' class='popUp' style='left:200px; top:100px;'>`

Comment: @FranciscoRagout - Please include your complete HTML (or a link to it, as appropriate) if you need additional support.

Comment: Any chance you have *two* elements with same id `projectInfo`?

Answer (score 1):

Without using function it can't work

```
 window.onload = function() {
   var popUp= document.getElementById('projectInfo');
   popUp.style.left=(tempX-310)+'px';
   popUp.style.top=(tempY-110)+'px';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

IE is having some known issues with  getElementById.This post may help .

1. http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-152-getelementbyid-returns.html
2. http://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of IE (and apparently Chrome and Firefox), getElementById would check for an object with the given id and if it didn't find it, it would take an element with that name.

IE9 doesn't do this, so you need to make sure you have an element with id = projectInfo, not just name=projectInfo.  We just discovered this throughout one of our applications.  Not great.