# Using document.getElementById() in IE 9 and previous versions

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a web page that is used to upload a file.  There are two input fields on the form.  One is of type text used to give the file a name in our database.  The other is of type file to select the file to upload.

```
<input type="text" name="docName" id="docName" size="35" value="" />
<input type="file" name="importFile" id="importFile" size="35" onchange="refreshFileName();"/>
```

I want to use JavaScript to extract the actual file name (minus the file path) from the "importFile" field once it's selected and auto-populate the field "docName" with that value.  My JavaScript looks like this:

```
function refreshFileName(){
var fileName = document.getElementById('importFile').value; 

var str = fileName.split("\\");
var length = str.length;

document.getElementById('docName').value = str[length-1]; 
}
```

This seems to work just file in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10 or 11.  But it doesn't seem to work in IE 9 or earlier versions.  Nothing I have tried seems to solve the problems.  Any suggestions on how I can get this to work with earlier version of IE (I've already thought of the idea "just tell my users not to use IE").

Comment: Older IEs don't have indexable strings.

Comment: You need to do some basic trouble shooting [(tutorial)](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) to see where it's failing. This at the very least involves `console.log()` to check your variables.

Comment: Tested in IE9, works fine.

Comment: I just tested it in IE9. its working fine.

Comment: `str` is an array of strings (or it should be), the result of `fileName.split()`. @Mike, try an alert(fileName) to see what you're getting. I cannot test in IE9

Comment: Allready asked, and i think answered: [document.getElementById() returns null on IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981337/document-getelementbyid-returns-null-on-ie9) and i found this as first result on google: [getElementById method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Maybe one of those help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
[How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById('importFile').value; 
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
```

This solution is useful for Windows and Unix paths.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is simply that you're getting back the full path in IE, try this:

```
var fileName = document.getElementById("importFile").value;
document.getElementById('docName').value = fileName.match(/[^\/\\]+$/);
```